# iOS SwiftUI - Google Sign-In error: Extra argument 'callback' in call

Tags: ios, swift

I got this code:

```
func signIn(){

   guard let presentingViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first?.rootViewController else {return}

    let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "xxxxx")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
        with: signInConfig,
        presenting: presentingViewController,
        callback: { user, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = "error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
            self.checkStatus()
        }
    )
}
```

I get the error "Extra argument 'callback' in call"

on the brace in

```
callback: { user, error in
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
    with: signInConfig,
    presenting: presentingViewController) { user, error in
      if let error = error {
            self.errorMessage = "error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
      }
      self.checkStatus()
    }
```

Refer to [Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in) section **4. Add a Google Sign-In button**

Comment: Alright will check and give feedback

Comment: Well the error is gone but now I have other errors when I try to login, the google docs are as almost always useless, they never tell how exactly and where to use those code snippets and what exactly they do. But I'll check since the question is answered, thanks!